# How to change upload directory path of ckfinder in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, ckeditor, ckfinder

I have integrated ckfinder 3 for php and after uploading images, getting the directory of uploaded images in the root, not in my project directory but I need inside my project directory like `project/upload/ckfinder/userfiles`

I am trying as follows in the `ckfinder/config.php` file of ckfinder:

```
$config['backends'][] = array(
    'name'         => 'default',
    'adapter'      => 'local',
    'baseUrl'      => base_url().'upload/ckfinder/userfiles/',
    //'root'         => '', // Can be used to explicitly set the CKFinder user files directory.
    'chmodFiles'   => 0777,
    'chmodFolders' => 0755,
    'filesystemEncoding' => 'UTF-8',
);
```

But It is not working 
Please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you should pass `FCPATH.'upload/ckfinder/userfiles'`, not sure about this library but dealing with files should be with absolute path.

Comment: I have also tried `FCPATH` @SherifSalah

Comment: Check the library itself to see how and where it stores the files, its a bit weird that it is using urls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`baseUrl` is optional for setting the backend and `root` is required.

If "project" is the folder where the CodeIgniter file `index.php` is found then use this backend

```
$config['backends'][] = array(
     'name'               => 'default',
     'adapter'            => 'local',
      //'baseUrl'            => '',
     'root'               => FCPATH .'upload/ckfinder/userfiles/',
     'chmodFiles'         => 0755,
     'chmodFolders'       => 0755,
     'filesystemEncoding' => 'UTF-8',
     'followSymlinks'     => true
 );
```